# Validation groups not working on Collection Type

Tags: symfony

So I have a form containing form collections. My parent form doesn't contain Form Type class. I created it directly via FormFactory likeso:

```
public function createBitcoinRateSettingForm()
    {
        $rateSettings = $this->em->getRepository(BitcoinRateSetting::class)->findRateSettings();

        if (empty($rateSettings)) {
            $rateSetting = new BitcoinRateSetting();
            $rateSetting->setIsDefault(true);
            $rateSettings[] = $rateSetting;
        }

        $bitcoinRateSettingForm = $this->formFactory->createBuilder()
            ->add('settings', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => BitcoinRateSettingType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Valid(),
                ],

            ])
            ->getForm()
        ;

        $bitcoinRateSettingForm->get('settings')->setData($rateSettings);

        return $bitcoinRateSettingForm;
    }
```

Then here is my BitcoinRateSettingType definition:

```
class BitcoinRateSettingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder
            ->add('rangeFrom', Type\TextType::class)
            ->add('rangeTo', Type\TextType::class)
            ->add('amountInEuros', Type\TextType::class)
            ->add('percentageAmountInEuros', Type\TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {   
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => BitcoinRateSetting::class,
            'validation_groups' => ['bitcoinRateDefault']
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is my validation.yml

```
DbBundle\Entity\BitcoinRateSetting:
    properties:
        rangeTo:
            - NotBlank: 
                message: "Range to should not be blank."
                groups: [bitcoinRateDefault]
            - NotNull:  
                message: "Range to should not be blank."
                groups: [bitcoinRateDefault]
        rangeFrom:
            - NotBlank: 
                message: "Range from should not be blank."
                groups: [bitcoinRateDefault]
            - NotNull: 
                message: "Range from should not be blank."
                groups: [bitcoinRateDefault]
```

As you can see, I set the default validation groups to **[bitcoinRateDefault]** but still validation is not getting triggered. Why is that so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you do seems rather ok, but I think you missed to define a top-level form validation groups:

```
$bitcoinRateSettingForm = $this->formFactory->createBuilder(null, 
        [ 
            'validation_groups' => ['bitcoinRateDefault']
        ])
        // The rest of of your code...
        ->add('settings', CollectionType::class, [
```

The first argument (the `null` above) represents initial data, so you might as well pass `$rateSettings` here instead in form:

```
['settings' => $rateSettings]
```

### UPDATE:

If you would like to validate only `settings` subset of the form, you need to "talk" to `validator` service directly:

If this is a Symfony 3.1+ (I think), inject `ValidatorInterface` in your controller/service. If this is Symfony 3.0-, you need to obtain `validator` from your container via `get()` call. Once you do you can:

```
$settings = $form->get('settings')->getData();
$violations = $validator->validate($settings, ['bitcoinRateDefault']);
```

If everything is valid, the `violations` collection will be empty (not `null`)...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi, what if I only want to apply the validation on subset of the settings collection only?

Comment: Huh, in that case, I think you could not really rely on form validation but you would have to talk to `validator` service in order to apply constrains. Updating the answer with that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cascade validation in formtype:

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
    'data_class' => BitcoinRateSetting::class,
    'validation_groups' => ['bitcoinRateDefault'],
    'cascade_validation' => true,
]);
```